# ClassNotFoundException in signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I got this error if I install and run a signed APK at my android device. This error does not come up if I just compile an app and run directly at device.

The Fragment, that seems to be missing is in my code in the project, not in any external library.

How could I investigate that error? i tried to rebuld, clean project etc.. Could I somehow find in APK if missing classes are created there?

hier is the error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

ComponentInfo{qua.com.bix/qua.com.bix.main.MainActivity}:
android.support.v4.app.q: Unable to instantiate fragment
qua.com.bix.main.MainLoadingFragment:
make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public at Android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    ....
    ....
    Caused by: android.support.v4.app.q: Unable to instantiate fragment qua.com.bix.main.MainLoadingFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    ....
    ....
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "qua.com.bix.main.MainLoadingFragment" on path: /data/app/qua.com.bix-1.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.support.v4.app.o.a(Unknown Source) 
    at android.support.v4.app.o.a(Unknown Source)
```

here is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "qua.com.bix"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    dexOptions{
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.quadriq.qlib:qlib@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
    compile 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.1'
}
```

**Update:** What helped for now, is disabling proguard, also adding `-dontobfuscate` to `proguard-rules.pro`. But is it a good practice to do this in that way?

the proguard-rules.pro is now:

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn org.joda.**
```

**Update 2**: petey answered my question.

Comment: can you post your entire progaurd config file?

Comment: We need to tell your proguard config to keep it easy for some classes

Comment: I put it in update.. I exclude some "warnings" there. It is the file you are asking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proguard is obfuscating your vital app classes.

add the following lines to your proguard config file so that proguard will not mess with your application's classes that extend `Activity`, `Application`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `ContentProvider`, `Preference`, & `Fragment` (support and normal).

```
# Base Android exclusions, required for proper function of various components
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

(if you arent using some of these feel free to remove those lines)

and then remove this line

```
-dontobfuscate
```

> What helped for now, is disabling proguard, also adding -dontobfuscate
>   to proguard-rules.pro. But is it a good practice to do this in that
>   way?

It is only best practice if you do not care if someone decompiles your application.  So, no. Mostly because you want to make a task like that as hard as possible on your production/release builds. Especially if you have In App Purchasing(IAP) or handle sensitive data.

Comment: It helped! But is better.. tot tell proguard to ignore that classes, or to disable it completely?

Comment: oops.  please see the edit for the answer to your question

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining! :) and sorry for my english.

Comment: While using Preference Settings from Jetpack I was having similar issue as OP (Class name not found.) 
Checked proguard rules if -keep was added for vital classes as mentioned in this comment. 
Immediately fixed the gnarly crash..