# ClassNotFoundException com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveSpace

Tags: android

It works without problem on the test device. But with the 'Generate Signed APK' Build and run, ClassNotFoundException:
com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveSpace error occurs. About the solution Thank you for your advice. Thank you.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.0.0'
```

...

```
/**
 * Retrieves the currently selected Drive file's metadata and contents.
 */
private void loadCurrentFile() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Retrieving...");
    final DriveFile file = mCurrentDriveId.asDriveFile();

    // Retrieve and store the file metadata and contents.
    mDriveResourceClient.getMetadata(file)
            .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Metadata, Task<DriveContents>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<DriveContents> then(@NonNull Task<Metadata> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        mMetadata = task.getResult();
                        return mDriveResourceClient.openFile(file, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
                    } else {
                        return Tasks.forException(task.getException());
                    }
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveContents>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DriveContents driveContents) {
            mDriveContents = driveContents;
            refreshUiFromCurrentFile();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: Did you try this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321595/classnotfoundexception-in-signed-apk]

Comment: Wow, I changed 'minifyEnabled' from true to false and it works fine. but I changed the 'minifyEnabled' back to true and I added '-keep public class * extends com.google.android.gms.drive.**' to Proguard file, The same error occurred.

Comment: Temporarily, I added the following code to build it.

void temp_function (DriveSpace tempDriveSpace, UserMetadata tempUserMetadata) {
        if (tempDriveSpace == null || tempUserMetadata == null) return;

        Log.i(TAG, tempDriveSpace.toString());
        Log.i(TAG, tempUserMetadata.toString());
}